# const void* as a complex number for MKL Blas routine in C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, intel-mkl

I got stuck with calling the MKL Blas function [cblas_zgemv](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/index.htm#GUID-A02DB70F-9704-42A4-9071-D409D783D911.htm)

There are two coeffitiens alpha and beta which are complex numbers:

```
alpha

REAL for sgemv

DOUBLE PRECISION for dgemv

COMPLEX for cgemv, scgemv

DOUBLE COMPLEX for zgemv, dzgemv
```

. But in the definition of the function:

```
void cblas_zgemv (const CBLAS_ORDER order, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA, 
const MKL_INT M, const MKL_INT N, const void *alpha, const void *A,
 const MKL_INT lda, const void *X, const MKL_INT incX, const void *beta, 
void *Y, const MKL_INT incY);
```

I have tried to set the alpha = complex(1.0,0) but this return me an error:

```
error: no suitable conversion function from "complex<double>" to "const void *" exists
```

What can I do? I don't understand what this const void* is...

Comment: Note: For the record, single-line wide-horizontal scrolling is a pita. If possible, break long lines into multiples for readability where suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects a pointer to the complex value, not the value itself. You'll need a variable to store the value in, and then pass the address of that:

```
std::complex<double> alpha(1,0);
cblas_zgemv(..., &alpha, ...);
```

I believe this is safe since `lapack_complex_double` is layout-compatible with (and, in C++, is an alias for) `std::complex<double>`. To be on the safe side, you might prefer to use `lapack_complex_double` when calling that library.